# How to stream objects at a time in Python 3.7+

Tags: python

Is there a way to stream objects to and from files in Python 3.7? It seems StreamReader isn't exactly what I'm looking for. The usage will be similar to:

```
class obj_t:
    def __init__(self):
        pass

strr = StreamHandler(file_pointer, expected_class = obj_t)
l = []
for obj in strr:
    assert type(obj) == obj_t
    l.append(obj)
```

Comment: Probably you want to serialize objects with e. g. "pickle" module.

Comment: Essentially, you are asking for a parser.

Comment: Yeah, `pickle` or `json`.  The problem with either is that you're never going to be able to serialize all Python objects.  Some defy serialization due to their nature, like file handle objects.  So you really need to choose your solution knowing what objects you want to serialize.  It may be that you have to do something special that no library could anticipate not knowing your particular objects.  The most common answer here is to stick with the primitive types and containers JSON serialization supports, and use the `json` module.  That's what I do.